# How to parallelize work in spark when working with multiple dataframes?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is parallelism among multiple dataframe supported in spark?

I have a task which net me 100s of dataframe, and I want to perform transformation and write to each of them.

However union them together seems to be not performant?

Are there any other concurrency primitive that work with multiple dataframes so that it scales horizontally with number of servers?

Comment: When you union dataframes and apply the transformations, the transformations are applied in an optimized and parallelized execution plan across nodes. Maybe you can change the transformations to have a more optimized solution.
You can check out the execution plan using ```output_df.explain()``` to see what the source of low performance is.

Comment: i think the transformation is performant, but union is not performant, is spark good for handling transformation for multiple dfs in parallel, what is the concurrency primitive for doing so?

Comment: union only put dataframes together. How can it not be performant?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a primitive to operate on multiple data frames.  But there is nothing stopping you from launching a batch script to saturate your cluster.  If that what you want to do.

Write the script for 1 data frame, then launch 100s of jobs to do the work.

Comment: How does yarn distribute all these dataframes to worker nodes? Is one node getting all the df, or the df is spread across the worker nodes via some policy?

Comment: It would sudo randomly assign the work across the entire cluster.  (It is random but if certaub nodes are already busy it will pick the none busy ones)